# Best solution for pagination results ajax codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, pagination

I made a scroll pagination on a system of posts/comments with jquery / Ajax and codeigniter everything work fine, but i exaplain the my problem with a example:

THERE IS USER A AND USER B

I'm user A and i wrote on the profile of the user B,
In the same time the user B scroll down for see the informations on his own profile but 1 record has been inserted on the database and the pagination doesn't work fine because load 1 result identical.

I thought that the solution can be a system of cache but i would like know the logic for use it with the pagination.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common solution to this problem is to have a pagination pass not the page, but the ID from the database of the last item shown. So instead of calling for `page X`, ajax calls for `items after item XX`.

So the database query will look like this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > 10 LIMIT 10`

instead of

`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`